# How can you listen to ember route changes?

Tags: ember.js, html5-history, popstate

How can you detect route changes  (# or popstate) outside an ember app? I've tried this but not had any luck: they never fire

```
 window.onhashchange = function locationHashChanged() {
      console.log(location.hash);
    };
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function locationHashChanged(e) {
      console.log(e.location);
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "outside an ember app"? The Ember app is the whole world. What are you planning to do when you detect a route change?

Comment: @torazaburo I just want the name of the new route. It's ok to detect this in the ember app to :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if there's a good way to do this in the public API. But if you're OK with a little trickery, you can use the properties described [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_get-current-route-name-path).

```
var applicationController = App.__container__.lookup('controller:application');
applicationController.addObserver('currentRouteName', function() {
    var currentRouteName = applicationController.get('currentRouteName');
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Can I do this from a component, not a controller? I say this as I want to do this in an addon with a component. I just want this functionality to be turned on on a per use case.

Comment: Sure, but there's no reason not to just put that directly into the application controller to avoid the container lookup, and just define a regular observer method on `currentRouteName` as you propose.

Comment: the currentRouteName and currentPath are only on the application controller, http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_get-current-route-name-path

Comment: If you're doing it from inside of a component you're not really 'outside' the app any more. But either way, you'll need the reference to the application controller, as Kingpin2k said.

Comment: @GJK cool I'm sold on this! One more thing, how can you recommend adding this to the addon in order to minimse the effect on the ember app using the addon? Should I just stick it in the **/addon/app/controllers/routeRecording**

Comment: I think I will pass a refernece to `App` into my component, is this possible? I will pass this in from my application controller in my dummy app I think..

Comment: To be honest, I'm not very familiar with Ember CLI. I can't really give you a best practice for this unfortunately.